# How to get aggregate column value and last month aggregate column value

Tags: sql, dax, powerbi-desktop, duckdb

In duckdb, I have a table named table1 with columns as date1, var1, var2, var3, value1; I want a group by sql statement, such as:

```
  select date_trunc('month', date1) as date_month, var1, [var2, [var3]], sum(value1) as this_month_value, sum('how to code') as last_month_value
  from table1 
  group by 1, 2, [3, [4]]
```

How can I do it of column 'last_month_value', and the var1, var2 or var3 will be dynamic. Because I will use this sql in superset, then the sql should be only one 'from' clause.

If I can make 'var1' or  'var2' or 'var3' static, and can use arbitrary sql technical, I can solve this problem, such as :

```
select aa.date_month, aa. var1, aa.this_month_value, bb.this_month_value as last_month_value
from
(
select date_trunc('month', date1) as date_month, var1, [var2, [var3]], sum(value1) as this_month_value
from table1 
group by 1, 2 
) as aa join 
(
select date_trunc('month', date1) as date_month, var1, [var2, [var3]], sum(value1) as this_month_value
from table1 
group by 1, 2 
) bb on aa.date_month = date_add(bb.date_month + interval 1 month) and aa.var1 = bb.var1
```

In microsoft Power bi Dax language, there is a function names calculate that can rewrite a filter base on column and inherited all other filters.

And we want to get result:

```
select '2023-03-01' as date_month, 'product 1' as var1, 12345 as this_month_value, 32032 as previous_month_value
```

if 2023-03-01 & product1's value1 is 12345, and 2023-02-01 & product1's value1 is 32032.

Comment: In Dax language, the metirc defination is not depended by filter columns.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please post an example that's more concrete? In any case, you may find the [`COLUMNS`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/star#columns-expression) expression helpful. You can run [lambda functions](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/star#columns-lambda-function) on its output for filtering/processing.

Comment: select '2023-03-01' as date_month,  'product 1' as var1, 12345 as this_month_value, 32032 as previous_month_value, if 2023-03-01 and product1 is 12345, and 2023-02-01 and product1 is 32032

Comment: Please edit and revise the original post.